# Specify flask project with static port 5000 in visual studio 2015

Tags: flask, visual-studio-2013

I am new in flask development , and am using visual studio , when i run the project , it random generates **ports** e.g `44744,84849,84458` each time i run  , how can i make it static to `5000` each time i run the project?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did was to remove all the lines from file `runserver.py` :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
HOST = environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
try:
    PORT = int(environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '5555'))
except ValueError:
    PORT = 5555
app.run(HOST, PORT)
```

and replaced them with :

```
app.run(port=5000,debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Port configuration will be available in `runserver.py` file.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
HOST = environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
try:
    PORT = int(environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '5555'))
except ValueError:
    PORT = 5555
app.run(HOST, PORT)
```

The above is the default configuration in Visual Studio Flash project. You can modify 5555 to 5000 or whatever you want.

Comment: but still it bring auto generated ports , how can i host it locally ?